# Having an error in my error log in Azure devops

Tags: azure, devops

Good day, I am getting this error log when running my test automated script (Visual Studio, Selenium, C#) in Azure Devops. It is running locally fine.  This is the error log I am getting in Azure Devops.

```
[07/16/2020 14:12:59 > b1b2b5: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[07/16/2020 14:12:59 > b1b2b5: SYS INFO] Run script 'run.cmd' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[07/16/2020 14:12:59 > b1b2b5: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[07/16/2020 14:12:59 > b1b2b5: INFO] 
[07/16/2020 14:12:59 > b1b2b5: INFO] D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\UserLogin\esnwqt2o.nav>dotnet UserLogin.dll  
[07/16/2020 14:12:59 > b1b2b5: ERR ] Unhandled exception. OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: The chromedriver.exe file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html.
[07/16/2020 14:12:59 > b1b2b5: ERR ]    at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService.FindDriverServiceExecutable(String executableName, Uri downloadUrl)
[07/16/2020 14:12:59 > b1b2b5: ERR ]    at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
[07/16/2020 14:12:59 > b1b2b5: ERR ]    at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
[07/16/2020 14:12:59 > b1b2b5: ERR ]    at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor()
[07/16/2020 14:12:59 > b1b2b5: ERR ]    at UserLogin.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Anneline\source\repos\UserLogin\UserLogin\Program.cs:line 20
[07/16/2020 14:12:59 > b1b2b5: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[07/16/2020 14:12:59 > b1b2b5: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766
```

Comment: It seems like you dont have the chromedriver.exe installed on the machine that runs the tests. It

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's failing because the chromedriver.exe is not found. Install following ChromeDriver Nuget package to your test solution -
[image]

Before building your test solution in the agent, run 'dotnet restore'.

Initialise driver as -

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver(); //using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome namespace
```

More details here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=azure-devops#create-your-test-project

Comment: So what you say is it must be fixed on Azure Devops side?

Comment: Which template in Visual Studio would you recommend using C# Selenium for running in Azure Devops?

Comment: Add chromedriver Nuget package to your test solution, so that you won't run into 'chromedriver.exe file does not exist' error. Unclear about the app you're testing or how it is being referenced.

To develop your test solution, you can use NUnit Test (.Net Core) tempelate, and in Azure Devops, you can use a .Net Core template (dotnet restore, build, test) while creating new pipeline.

Comment: please specify which .Net Core to use.  .Net Core console or ??

Comment: It is a web application, on Chrome and Azure Devops

Comment: This is my code using NUnit Test (.Net Core) template:

Comment: using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;

namespace NUnitTestProject1
{
    public class Tests
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            //Navigate to Login Page
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https:******");
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        }

        [Test]
        {

        }
    }
}

Comment: But the web browser doesn't open

Comment: Is it the same error? Did you add the Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver Nuget package (by jsakamoto) to your solution as pointed in the answer above?

Comment: I got this in the Console:  C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe (process 17852) exited with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .

Comment: Yes I did add the Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver

Comment: I guess you're new to .NET Core development. As I understand from your above comment, you're using .NET Core NUnit project. In that case, you have to trigger the test from test explorer in VS IDE or using 'dotnet test' command. You need to have at least one method under [Test] attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the chromedriver.exe file in your agent. Is the agent Self Hosted? If so then you can use the following: https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/selenium/

If it is a microsoft hosted agent then it could be another issue since chromedriver should be installed already if you are using windows latest.
Here is a link that may help you to debug the environment path issue if you are using the Microsoft hosted agent:
https://www.koskila.net/how-to-use-the-right-version-of-the-webdriver-on-hosted-agents-in-azure-devops/

You can find the chrome drivers for download here if needed: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Answer (score 0):

Would be that your project cannot find the chromedriver.exe file, try this:

1. Properties of the project that's gonna use the Chromedriver
2. Pick "Build"
3. Write: _PUBLISH_CHROMEDRIVER on the "conditional compilation symbols"
   [image: Conditional compilatio symbols]

After that, your pipeline is gonna success!!

[image: Succeded!]